# Monotouch: Manipulating many images - Out of memory

Tags: memory-management, xamarin.ios, uiimage

I'm looking for a way to process many images, but not run out of memory. When my app first runs it has to create a number of thumbnails and store them locally. This only happens one time.

I'm getting out of memory errors though.

Roughly I am going this:

```
 [Loop BigPaths]
  sourceImg = UIImage.FromFile (nextBigpath);
  img = UIImageTools.MakeSquare (sourceImg, 50,3);
  img.AsJPEG ().Save (path, NSDataWritingOptions.Atomic, out err);
  sourceImg.Dispose ();
  sourceImg = null;
  img.Dispose ();
  img = null;     
  [end loop]
```

**UPDATE**:

To fix it, I am now calling GC.Collect() after every 10 items, waiting 50 milliseconds in a Thread.Sleep().

I also made `sourceImg` `img` defined outside the loop.

With these 2 changes, I am no longer getting memory errors.

Comment: This should not happen since your manually disposing the UIImage. But maybe some other parts of the code are not disposing their resource ? e.g. does the image manipulation code allocates ? It would be much easier to help you if we could see the offending code and run it in a loop to duplicate the `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: Can you show the code in GetImage? There are certain ways of loading images that will keep them all cached forever (UIImage.FromBundle).

Comment: I updated the code with my fix. I don't fully understand why it works but it does. Perhaps using GC.Collect() every 10 images and using a Thread.Sleep() helps?

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com Thanks, I'll try something similar. Could you tell me the approximate size of the images ? note: calling `GC.Collect` can help since the managed objects are generally small (e.g. a pointer to the native image) while the *real* memory size can be very large (but the GC is not aware of this, unmanaged, size). OTOH calling Dispose should take care of that (unless something else gets created).

Comment: It's working now that I reuse the image objects by defining them outside the main loop. Once I added that and a GC.Collect + Thread.SLeep(50) after every 50 images, it worked perfectly. The images are about 150k Jpgs and we're create 50x50 thumbnails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found worked.

Create the image variables outside the loop and reuse them, making sure that after each use .Dispose() is called.

After 50 images call GC.Collect() then Thread.Sleep(50) to give the GC time to clean up.

After that there were no memory issues.